# Выборка из бд в JSON массив и отправка на сервер на android

Tags: android, json

Вообщем есть такая задачка надо каждый определенный отрезок времени загядывать в бд и если есть данные ложить их в массив и отправлять на сервер где они будут записаны в бд. Я решил сделать это с помощью таймера, но наткнулся вот на что, у меня в бд 8 столбов и я хз как и положить в массив чтобы потом на сервере с помощью php все это распихать как мне надо. Вот мой код:

```
mTimer = new Timer();
    mMyTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    SQLiteDatabase DateBase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    Cursor v = DateBase.query("OFFLINETABLE", null, null, null, null, null, null);
                    ArrayList toServer = new ArrayList();
                    if (v.moveToFirst()) {
                        do{
                            //вот тут делается выборка но я хз что писать
                        } while (v.moveToNext());
                    } else {
                        v.close();
                    }
                    dbHelper.close();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    mTimer.schedule(mMyTimerTask, 0, 180000);
```

вот такие дела помогите плиз.

Comment: Фу, использование курсора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сидел думал перебирал всякие мануалы и вот что надумал.

```
mTimer = new Timer();
    mMyTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    SQLiteDatabase DateBase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    Cursor v = DateBase.query("OFFLINETABLE", null, null, null, null, null, null);
                    ArrayList toServer = new ArrayList();
                    JSONObject dataToServer = new JSONObject();
                    if (v.moveToFirst()) {
                        do{
                            try {
                                dataToServer.put("ID_USER", v.getInt(v.getColumnIndex("ID_USER")));
                                dataToServer.put("IDDOHRASH", v.getInt(v.getColumnIndex("IDDOHRASH")));
                                dataToServer.put("CURRENTDATA", v.getInt(v.getColumnIndex("CURRENTDATA")));
                                dataToServer.put("IDSCHET", v.getInt(v.getColumnIndex("IDSCHET")));
                                dataToServer.put("ACCOUNT", v.getString(v.getColumnIndex("ACCOUNT")));
                                dataToServer.put("IDKAT", v.getInt(v.getColumnIndex("IDKAT")));
                                dataToServer.put("RASHOD", v.getString(v.getColumnIndex("RASHOD")));
                                dataToServer.put("MONEY", v.getFloat(v.getColumnIndex("MONEY")));
                                dataToServer.put("VALUTA", v.getString(v.getColumnIndex("VALUTA")));
                                dataToServer.put("KOMMENT", v.getString(v.getColumnIndex("KOMMENT")));
                                dataToServer.put("METKA", v.getString(v.getColumnIndex("METKA")));
                                dataToServer.put("IDSCHETNAV", v.getInt(v.getColumnIndex("IDSCHETNAV")));
                                dataToServer.put("CUSTOMEKATEGORY", v.getString(v.getColumnIndex("CUSTOMEKATEGORY")));
                                dataToServer.put("TYPESCHETA", v.getString(v.getColumnIndex("TYPESCHETA")));
                                dataToServer.put("CUSTOMEKATEGORYMONEY", v.getFloat(v.getColumnIndex("CUSTOMEKATEGORYMONEY")));
                                dataToServer.put("IDLAYOUT", v.getInt(v.getColumnIndex("IDLAYOUT")));
                                dataToServer.put("DEVICE", v.getInt(v.getColumnIndex("DEVICE")));
                                dataToServer.put("DEL", v.getInt(v.getColumnIndex("DEL")));
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            toServer.add(dataToServer);
                        } while (v.moveToNext());
                    } else {
                        v.close();
                    }
                    JSONArray arrayToServer = new JSONArray(toServer);
                    dbHelper.close();
                    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                    params.put("email", login);
                    params.put("DateArray", arrayToServer);
                    upadteToServer(params);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    mTimer.schedule(mMyTimerTask, 0, 180000);
```

может будет работать